# Mejorar el stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` PROCEDURE `actualizar_terrarios_por_especie`(IN especiecambiada BIGINT)
BEGIN  
    UPDATE terrarios t
    INNER JOIN especie_terrario et ON et.idterrario = t.id
    INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie 
    SET t.temperatura_maxima = (SELECT MIN(e.temperatura_maxima) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.temperatura_minima = (SELECT MAX(e.temperatura_minima) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.temperatura_maxima_hiber = (SELECT MIN(e.temperatura_hib_maxima) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.temperatura_minima_hiber = (SELECT MAX(e.temperatura_hib_minima) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.humedad_maxima = (SELECT MIN(e.humedad_maxima) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.humedad_minima = (SELECT MAX(e.humedad_minima) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.horas_luz = (SELECT MIN(e.horas_luz) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
        , t.horas_luz_hiber = (SELECT MIN(e.horas_luz_hib) FROM especie_terrario et INNER JOIN especies e ON e.id = et.idespecie WHERE et.idterrario = t.id)
    WHERE et.idespecie = especiecambiada;
END
```

Lo que hace y quiero que haga es que, cuando yo actualice información o borre de la tabla de especies una fila, los terrarios que contengan o hayan contenido esa especie actualicen su información en base a todas las especies que habiten dentro en ese momento.
Bien. Esto funciona, pero entiendo que se puede mejorar. Mucho. Pero no me sale el mejorarlo.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Por cada columna lees el mínimo y máximo con una subconsulta. Parece más lógico, hacer una lectura inicial, usando una tabla de expresión común, y aplicar las updates de las columnas que correspondan en función de la lectura inicial. [Mysql cte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo haces con un TRIGGER? Con tu SP parecería que intentas reinventar la rueda.

Comment: Javi fer2, Me lo apunto.
Cedano, porque el trigger no me deja actualizar varias líneas a la vez. Ya lo he intentado. Quizá mal, si, pero bueno.

Comment: Con un `FOR EACH ROW` puedes actualizar todas las filas que haga falta.

Comment: ¿Mejorar en qué sentido? Porque generalmente todo se puede mejorar, pero lanzada la pregunta así, en general, puede resultar demasiado amplia. Si quieres mejorar algo específico, estaría bien, pero haría falta que digas qué es exactamente eso que quieres mejorar (o qué es lo que no está funcionando bien, que también se vale).

Comment: jachguate, simplemente saber si se podía hacer con menos llamadas, más eficiente en cuanto al tiempo, que no use tanta memoria...

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente tienes subconsultas a nivel de columna que son prácticamente iguales, efectivamente no es una patrón muy performante que digamos, 8 subconsultas multiplicado por cada fila que actualizas.

Conceptualmente necesitas saber ciertos valores máximos y mínimos a partir de `especie_terrario`, conviene entonces calcularlos previamente de un sola vez:

```
SELECT  et.idterrario,
        MIN(e.temperatura_maxima)       as temperatura_maxima,
        MAX(e.temperatura_minima)       as temperatura_minima,
        MIN(e.temperatura_hib_maxima)   as temperatura_maxima_hiber,
        MAX(e.temperatura_hib_minima)   as temperatura_minima_hiber,
        MIN(e.humedad_maxima)           as humedad_maxima,
        MAX(e.humedad_minima)           as humedad_minima,
        MIN(e.horas_luz)                as horas_luz,
        MIN(e.horas_luz_hib)            as horas_luz_hiber
        FROM especie_terrario et 
        INNER JOIN especies e 
            ON e.id = et.idespecie 
        WHERE et.idespecie = especiecambiada
        GROUP BY et.idterrario
```

Ahora simplemente hay que aprovechar esta subconsulta en la de `update`:

```
UPDATE  terrarios
    SET    temperatura_maxima       = m.temperatura_maxima,
           temperatura_minima       = m.temperatura_minima,
           temperatura_maxima_hiber = m.temperatura_maxima_hiber,
           temperatura_minima_hiber = m.temperatura_minima_hiber,
           humedad_maxima           = m.humedad_maxima,
           humedad_minima           = m.humedad_minima,
           horas_luz                = m.horas_luz,
           horas_luz_hiber          = m.horas_luz_hiber
    FROM terrarios t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  et.idterrario,
            MIN(e.temperatura_maxima)       as temperatura_maxima,
            MAX(e.temperatura_minima)       as temperatura_minima,
            MIN(e.temperatura_hib_maxima)   as temperatura_maxima_hiber,
            MAX(e.temperatura_hib_minima)   as temperatura_minima_hiber,
            MIN(e.humedad_maxima)           as humedad_maxima,
            MAX(e.humedad_minima)           as humedad_minima,
            MIN(e.horas_luz)                as horas_luz,
            MIN(e.horas_luz_hib)            as horas_luz_hiber
            FROM especie_terrario et 
            INNER JOIN especies e 
                ON e.id = et.idespecie
            WHERE et.idespecie = especiecambiada
            GROUP BY et.idterrario
    ) m
    ON m.idterrario = t.id
```